# How to return a value from a Fetch Api

Tags: javascript, fetch, fetch-api

I have the following code and it executes perfectly.

```
var website = "youtube.com"
const getViews = (website) => {
  fetch("/api?Action=TrafficHistory&Range=1&Output=json&ResponseGroup=History&Url=" + website, {
    headers: {
      "X-Api-Key": "hidden"
    }
  })
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => JSON.stringify(data))
  .then((data) =>{
    let parsedData = JSON.parse(data)
    console.log(parsedData)
  })
  
}

getViews(website)
```

Instead of console logging the data I wanted to return the variable **parsedData** that holds the data. I tried modifying the like so but it gives me a value of undefined.

```
var website = "youtube.com"
const getViews = (website) => {
  fetch("/api?Action=TrafficHistory&Range=1&Output=json&ResponseGroup=History&Url=" + website, {
    headers: {
      "X-Api-Key": "hidden"
    }
  })
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => JSON.stringify(data))
  .then((data) =>{
    let parsedData = JSON.parse(data)
    return parsedData
  })
  
}
let holdData = getViews(website)
console.log(holdData)
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Your `getViews` doesn’t return anything. `return parsedData` isn’t returned anywhere as the Promise chain simply ends there and the return value isn’t used.

Comment: If API's response is in JSON format, why do you use `JSON.stringify` and then `JSON.parse`?

Answer (score 1):

Return the promise chain as well

```
const getViews = (website) => {
  return fetch("/api?Action=TrafficHistory&Range=1&Output=json&ResponseGroup=History&Url=" + website, {
    headers: {
      "X-Api-Key": "hidden"
    }
  })
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => JSON.stringify(data))
  .then((data) =>{
    let parsedData = JSON.parse(data)
    return parsedData
  })
  
}
```

Comment: This won't return the variable; it will return a promise. Call to `getViews` function will either need to be  _awaited_ or call `then` method on it: `getViews(...).then(data => { ... })`. In short, OP can't do what they are trying to do - at-least not reliably.

Comment: Oh yeah right but this is usually what you get unless you use some sort of promise wrapper